# Debian, how to change md name using initramfs script and not livecd?

Tags: debian, raid, mdadm, initramfs

Is possible to change an md name while the md is still active? AFAIK is not possible

```
mdadm -A --update=name --name=ibmlinux-root /dev/md126
ls /dev/md/126_0 
/dev/md/126_0 
ls /dev/md/ibmlinux-root
error: no such file or directory
```

Is possible only to stop it, update the name, then reassemble it

```
mdadm --stop /dev/md126
mdadm -A --update=name --name=ibmlinux-root /dev/md126
```

now the problem... the /dev/md126 is a root device, mounted on /
so is impossbile to umount it.

The best thing is to reboot with live-cd and rename it, then reboot (works, I have did it a lot of times).

But I want a more fast and easy solution, Debian use scripts on this directory

```
/usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/local-premount
```

my idea is to create a script, rename the md, then after reboot remove the script.

I have create the script

vim /usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/local-premount/md

```
#!/bin/sh -e

PREREQ=""

prereqs()
{
        echo "$PREREQ"
}

case $1 in
# get pre-requisites
prereqs)
        prereqs
        exit 0
        ;;
esac

mdadm --stop /dev/md126
mdadm -A --update=name --name=ibmlinux-root /dev/md126
```

I make it executable, update initramfs and grub

```
chmod +x /usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/local-premount/md                                                   
update-initramfs -cv -k all
update-grub2
```

I reboot and voilà..has the new name as..127! :(

```
   ls /dev/md/127_0 
   /dev/md/127_0 
   ls /dev/md/ibmlinux-root
   error: no such file or directory
```

What I miss?
I tried also to put the script in /etc/initramfs-tools/scripts/init-premount/ and nothing change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have forgot, my root array was created with 0.90 metadata, I have recreate it with metadata 1.2 (modern grub can boot it without no problem), and to update the name I have simply to edit /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf (metadata 0.90 don't allow name on md raid)

```
vim /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf

ARRAY /dev/md/root   metadata=1.2 name=root   UUID=331728d9:c4d12r4f:f589d3ze:01ab3c17
ARRAY /dev/md/backup metadata=1.2 name=backup UUID=429845f1:d5e24f5g:8135dgte:120ff5c0
```

update initramfs and grub and reboot.

```
update-initramfs -cv -k all
update-grub2
shutdown -r now
```

after reboot..

```
ls /dev/md
ibmlinux:backup  ibmlinux:root
```

Using the scripts of initramfs is also possible to change name of md127 to md0 or whatever we want

Create a script in /etc/initramfs-tools/scripts/init-premount

vim /etc/initramfs-tools/scripts/init-premount/md

```
#!/bin/sh

# Stop lvm
lvm vgchange -an vg-backup
lvm vgchange -an vg-ppclinux
sleep 3

# Stop raid
mdadm --stop /dev/md126
mdadm --stop /dev/md127
sleep 3

# Assemble with new names 
mdadm -A /dev/md0 /dev/sda2 /dev/sdb2
mdadm -A /dev/md1 /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdd1
sleep 3

# Create the symlinks
mkdir /dev/md
ln -sv /dev/md1 /dev/md/ibmlinux:backup
ln -sv /dev/md0 /dev/md/ibmlinux:root

# Start lvm
lvm vgchange -ay vg-ppclinux
lvm vgchange -ay vg-backup
```

update permissions

```
chmod 755 /etc/initramfs-tools/scripts/init-premount/md
```

update initramfs and grub

```
update-initramfs -cv -k all
update-grub2
```

and after reboot..

```
find /dev/md -ls
    11344      0 drwxr-xr-x   2 root     root           80 nov  8 06:12 /dev/md
    11345      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root            8 nov  8 06:12 /dev/md/ibmlinux:root -> /dev/md0
     9440      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root            8 nov  8 06:12 /dev/md/ibmlinux:backup -> /dev/md1
```

I only get this error/warning message on log

```
PV /dev/md0 9:0 is duplicate for PVID ........ on 9:126 /dev/md126 failed to create online file
```

but all works fine (pvs, lvcreate, mdadm..)